# entering manage.py runserver in the shell, the Django server opens Texteditor instead of starting the server

Tags: python, django

When I type manage.py runserver in the shell, there only opens my text editor, instead of starting the server. I do not understand this issue. The documentation of django says, the server should start.

Comment: what is the server of course ? *I guess you have already running server? please share more details about your question.*

Comment: I try to run the server but when i type manage.py runserver in the cmd, it only opens Pycharm. I am in the correct dir and im working within my created environment. I think the problem is that i used Pycharm recently to work on programs and now all the .py files refer directly to Pycharm so the console cant run the program. But what can I do about it?

Answer (score 0):

to start the server u should type `python manage.py runserver` and
before this make sure that you are in the correct dir and also make sure you are working within your created environment.

Comment: I am doing exactly that but the cmd only opens Pycharm, the server doesnt start

Answer (score 0):

Solution was to go in windows default settings and change the program to open .py files to python